# PostgreSQL "group by" with "order by" and "limit" works unexpectedly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL 13 DB and I'm investigating perfomance of a one big query with multiple joins and found that "group by" togeher with "order by" and "limit" works unexpectedly to me.

I've tracked it down to the most simple case so to run my queries you can create a table

```
create table test(id serial primary key, field text);
insert into test(field) select md5(random()::text) from generate_series(1, 10000);
```

And lets add an index

```
create index test_field_index on test(field);
```

1. Test index

```
    explain analyze 
    select * from test
    order by field
    limit 25;
```

```
 Limit  (cost=0.29..2.24 rows=25 width=37) (actual time=0.048..0.082 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using test_field_index on test  (cost=0.29..782.28 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=0.047..0.076 rows=25 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.339 ms
 Execution Time: 0.099 ms
```

All is good.

2. Add group by field

```
explain analyze 
select * from test
group by id
order by field
limit 25;
```

```
Limit  (cost=591.19..591.26 rows=25 width=37) (actual time=11.125..11.130 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=591.19..616.19 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=11.124..11.126 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: field
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=209.00..309.00 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=6.267..8.303 rows=10000 loops=1)
               Group Key: id
               Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1425kB
               ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..184.00 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=0.008..1.685 rows=10000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.120 ms
 Execution Time: 11.218 ms
```

See that "group by" ignores "limit" and "order by" doesn't use index.

3. Try to order by id instead

```
explain analyze 
select * from test
group by id
order by id
limit 25;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.29..1.24 rows=25 width=37) (actual time=0.018..0.040 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Group  (cost=0.29..382.29 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=0.017..0.035 rows=25 loops=1)
         Group Key: id
         ->  Index Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.29..357.29 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=0.014..0.023 rows=25 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.099 ms
 Execution Time: 0.062 ms
```

Looks good again.

4. Order by id and field together

```
explain analyze 
select * from test
group by id
order by id, field
limit 25;
```

```
 Limit  (cost=0.33..2.41 rows=25 width=37) (actual time=0.033..0.036 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Incremental Sort  (cost=0.33..832.29 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=0.032..0.034 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: id, field
         Presorted Key: id
         Full-sort Groups: 1  Sort Method: quicksort  Average Memory: 26kB  Peak Memory: 26kB
         ->  Group  (cost=0.29..382.29 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=0.011..0.021 rows=26 loops=1)
               Group Key: id
               ->  Index Scan using test_pkey on test  (cost=0.29..357.29 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=0.010..0.014 rows=26 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.072 ms
 Execution Time: 0.052 ms
```

Much better than [2], but anyway "order by" still doesn't use index on field.

5. Try to reverse fields in "order by"

```
explain analyze 
select * from test
group by id
order by field, id
limit 25;
```

```
 Limit  (cost=591.19..591.26 rows=25 width=37) (actual time=11.488..11.493 rows=25 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=591.19..616.19 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=11.487..11.489 rows=25 loops=1)
         Sort Key: field, id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 28kB
         ->  HashAggregate  (cost=209.00..309.00 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=5.838..8.118 rows=10000 loops=1)
               Group Key: id
               Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 1425kB
               ->  Seq Scan on test  (cost=0.00..184.00 rows=10000 width=37) (actual time=0.008..1.349 rows=10000 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 0.105 ms
 Execution Time: 11.562 ms
```

The same as [2] - it ignores all indexes and limit.

6. Try [5] with composite index

```
create index test_field_id_index on test(field, id);
```

Nothing has changed at all. Actually I added all 3 possible indexes and it doesn't change nothing.

With my real original query on the production DB the difference between [4] and [6] is ~11ms vs ~1200ms. So for now I just put id column as the first one in "order by" and got huge improvement but my first attempt was to fix it like [6] and I was surprised that it doesn't help.

So my questions are:

1. Why doesn't "order by" use index for the columns different from id if "group by" is present?
2. Why does "group by" ignore "limit" in cases [2] and [5]?
3. Why wasn't new index used in [6]?
4. Why does "group by" use 26 rows in [4]? I guess it needs to do n+1 but just wondering why, since in [3] it is not so?

Comment: What is the point of **grouping by the primary key**? Every group will be the aggregate of exactly 1 row, which means that you're essentially doing nothing at all, except confusing the SQL Query Analyzer. All your queries are meaningless, and analyzing them is pointless. Remove `group by id` from all the queries, and the query *result* will be exactly the same, but you'll get better access plans.

Comment: As I mentioned it is a simplified query made for demonstaration purpose, in the real query I need to group by primary key because it contains joins

Comment: Well, then analyze those queries. What you're doing here is just a waste of time. Any change to a query may entirely change the access plan (as well illustrated by the queries here), so analyzing a non-join query is useless for optimizing a joined query.

Comment: Actually I came to these dumb queries by removing things step by step and looking at plan on each step, adding a join and aggregation just to justify grouping by id doesn't change relevant parts of plans and my questions.

Comment: If you're wondering here is my original query https://explain.depesz.com/s/NtOJ
And here is version with sorting just by id https://explain.depesz.com/s/IUD9
As you can see the first one ignores limit and index on ("proposalDate", id) the same way as examples here

Answer (score 1):

> See that "group by" ignores "limit" and "order by" doesn't use index.

This is how it should be. all the groups need to be created before they can be ordered and limited.

> Much better than [2], but anyway "order by" still doesn't use index on field.

that wouldn't help performance, the id index is sufficient because it's a unique index.  filed has no information that could change the order.

Comment: Does it mean that [3] is just a special optimization case as group there uses limit?

Comment: About [4] I understand that adding one more column to the "order by" after a uniq key doesn't change order, but then why is the plan not the same as in [3], is optimizator just not smart enough?